# Is there a better way to use applySpec here

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I think the redundancy here can be removed by using some function insde ramda but I am very new to this library so i cant think of how.Some help would be really appreciated

```
let lib = {
    getFormattedPropsForUser: R.compose(
        R.pickBy(R.identity),
        R.applySpec({
            username: R.prop('username'),
            password: R.prop('password')
        })),
    getFormattedQueryParamsForUser: R.compose(
        R.pickBy(R.identity),
        R.applySpec({
            _id: R.prop('_id'),
            username: R.prop('username'),
            password: R.prop('password')
        })
    )

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the common part of both applications to a function, and add the ability to add more items to the spec using partial application and [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals).

**Example:**

```js
const forUser = spec => R.compose(
  R.pickBy(R.identity),
  R.applySpec({
    ...spec,
    username: R.prop('username'),
    password: R.prop('password')
  })
)

const lib = {
  getFormattedPropsForUser: forUser(),
  getFormattedQueryParamsForUser: forUser({ _id: R.prop('_id') }),
}

const test = { _id: 'id', username: 'username', password: 'password' }

console.log(lib.getFormattedPropsForUser(test))

console.log(lib.getFormattedQueryParamsForUser(test))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your functions quite a bit, and abstract the common parts out relatively easily.  Here `getActualProps` does much the same as your `applySpec`/`pickBy(identity)` shuffle, with the actual fields parameterized.  Then the two functions (or library methods) can be written in terms of it.

```js
const getActualProps = (names) => pickBy((v, k) => includes(k, names))

const getFormattedPropsForUser = getActualProps(['username', 'password'])
const getFormattedQueryParamsForUser = getActualProps(['_id', 'username'])


// Test
const fred = {_id: 1, name: 'fred', username: 'fflint', password: 'dino'}
const wilma = {_id: 2, name: 'wilma', username: 'wilma42'}
const barney = {_id: 3, name: 'barney', password: 'bam*2'}

console.log(getFormattedPropsForUser(fred))         //~> {password: "dino", username: "fflint"}
console.log(getFormattedQueryParamsForUser(fred))   //~> {_id: 1, username: "fflint"}
console.log(getFormattedPropsForUser(wilma))        //~> {username: "wilma42"}
console.log(getFormattedQueryParamsForUser(wilma))  //~> {_id: 2, username: "wilma42"}
console.log(getFormattedPropsForUser(barney))       //~> {password: "bam*2"}
console.log(getFormattedQueryParamsForUser(barney)) //~> {_id: 3}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {pickBy, includes} = ramda    </script>
```